# json - javascript data types

Tags: javascript, json

Pls some clarifications:

```
var a = '{"item":"earth", "color":"blue", "weight":920}';
```

what is data type of `a` - `string` or `array` ?

```
var b = JSON.parse(a);
```

what is data type of `b` - `object` or `array` ?

Comment: `a` is a string, `b` is an object. You could have found that out via the `typeof` operator. *edit* actually `b` will be `undefined` because your JSON is invalid. Only `"` may be used for quoting in JSON.

Comment: @Pointy and how to get array instead of object?

Comment: You can't. Arrays have numbered indexes, not named keys.

Comment: You could use `Object.values(b)` to get an array of the values from the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**a** is a string and **b** is an object

```
var a = '{"item":"earth", "color":"blue", "weight":920}';
var b = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(typeof a); // string
console.log(typeof b); // object
```

If you need to cast to an array, you can **JSON.parse(a)** to an object. Now **b** is an object and you can:

```
var c = Object.entries(b);
console.log(c);
```

Now **c** is your array.

Although c will be an array of arrays:

> [ [ 'item', 'earth' ], [ 'color', 'blue' ], [ 'weight', 920 ] ]

I'm guessing you probably want this:

```
var arr = [];
for (let i in b) {
   arr[i] = b[i];
}
console.log(arr);
```

> [ item: 'earth', color: 'blue', weight: 920 ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? And what do you mean by "How to get array?"

Comment: means - how to get array instead of object - just that

Comment: Updated answer... Does that solve what your trying to do?

Comment: `Object.values(b)` vs `Object.entries(b)`